# Custom user interface object

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, xcode4

How i may do "inform panel" like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think this is chrome desktop notifications check google chrome API

Comment: This is not chrome notification. This is wiget from dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

Make an HUD panel in Interface builder? Or a textured window and set its texture to what you want?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a non-opaque borderless window:

```
NSPanel *window = [[NSPanel alloc] initWithContentRect:windowFrame styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
```

It is recommended to use NSPanel because it can become key only if needed (see `setBecomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded`)
You also need to have your custom subclass of NSPanel and override `canBecomeKeyWindow` if you need some user interaction inside that window.

Then you can layout your content view in xib or create custom subclass of `NSView` to represent your window's content view and set it to the custom window:

```
[window setContentView:<your content view>];
```

And finally present window on screen:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

If you wish your window appear over any other windows you can play with `windowLevel` property of `NSWindow` class, but be careful and follow Apple Human Interface Guidelines :)

Comment: I mean "inform panel", not window.

Comment: Everything you see in Mac OS X are windows. So "inform panel" is also a window.

Comment: Andriy, u not understand me, i mean user interface object "inform panel". Pleas see screenshots.

Comment: Hm... Now I understand what do you mean. Then it should be regular NSView subclass. The only problem I see is a reflection on top of whole view.

Comment: Yes, u understand me. I use custom NSView for drawing border "inform panel"      [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    NSRect bRect = CGRectInset([self bounds], 0, 0); 
    NSBezierPath *border = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bRect xRadius:8 yRadius:8];
    [border setLineWidth:0.5]; 
    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    [border stroke];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState]; and then add to custom View button with style Gradient. Set it size as size custom View, but when i run app the corner of my object not rounded.

Comment: I also use NSBox...and add in a box Button with style Gradient...But corner of my object not rounded...

Comment: Are you sure you see NSBezierPath you're drawing at all? Try to change its color to red for debugging purposes, inset bounding rect by 0.5 px and set line width to 1 px. You should see red rounded rect after view is drawn.

Comment: I don't see NSBezierPath when button in a view, but when i remove button i see. I do as u say, but this haven't effect.